# Get the value that comes after the ? operator in the URL

Tags: php

I want to get the value that will come after the '?' operator, for example:

```
www.blabla.com/any.php?h r u
```

I want to get this value "h r u", and to search this key in my database. I've already tried this:

```
$_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]
```

This function is working fine but when I searched these values it prints like this "h%20r%20u" in my database from this query:

```
$query="SELECT * FROM databasename WHERE colum LIKE'%$link%'";
```

It will print link this " h%20r%20u no record found " and my database can't find 
this value. How can i solve my problem?

Comment: **warning** your code maybe suseptible to sql injection attacks.

Comment: Just a quick aside - that should be `SELECT * FROM tablename`, not `databasename`.

Comment: replace the spaces with a '+'. That is the propper way of doing spaces in urls.

Answer (score 3):

Check out the [urldecode](http://php.net/urldecode) function.

Answer (score 0):

You should, as pointed out, use `urldecode($string)`.
For SQL Injections, just escape the value in your query:

```
$link = mysql_real_escape_string(urldecode($_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]));
$query="SELECT * FROM databasename WHERE colum LIKE'%$link%'";
```

if you use **mysql** or **mysqli** to make queries.
Use `PDO::quote` instead to escape if you use PDO.